In deriving the Lorentz transformation, how does one argue that a horizontal line $t=t_0$ maps to a line in $(x’,t’)$-coordinates?
Consider two inertial reference frames $K$ and $K’$ with respective coordinate systems $(x,t)$ and $(x’,t’)$. Let $f : (x,t) \mapsto (x’,t’)$ be the Lorentz transform from one coordinate system to the other.
In deriving the formula for $f$ one first argues that $f$ must be a linear function in $x$ and $t$. Indeed, as the argument goes, $f$ maps lines in $(x,t)$-coordinates to lines in $(x’,t’)$-coordinates because in either case a line corresponds to the path of a particle in uniform motion (constant velocity), and by the principle of relativity one should be able to assign a meaning to uniform motion in a way that is independent of the choice of coordinates.
What about the horizontal line $t=t_0$? A posteriori we know that it does not correspond to a horizontal line in $(x’,t’)$ because simultaneity is a relative concept. But how does one argue that it is still a line? More generally, what about a non-horizontal line corresponding to a velocity (i.e. $\Delta x / \Delta t$) greater than $c$, such that the particle analogy becomes non-physical? How does one argue in these cases?
Many thanks.

@JohnRennie Quite right, thank you. I meant particles with uniform motion (i.e. constant velocity, or zero acceleration). I’ve updated the question.

Are you saying the intuitive argument fails for the line $t = \textrm{const}$ because it cannot be the trajectory of a moving particle? If so that's true but that means only that the intuitive argument has a limited scope. Intuition is generally a dangerous approach to SR.

You should state precisely which particular choices are being made in your derivation. There are many different treatments on the topic and it is difficult to know which one you are complaining about. For example, a good treatment starting from Minkowski diagrams would begin with explaining how coördinates would be laid out, operationally and theoretically, and then it is obvious that lines transform into lines. Also, it is much more common that vertical lines are $x=$ const rather than $t=$ const.

@naturallyInconsistent I am essentially following Einstein’s popular exposition Relativity: the Special and General Theory wherein he derives the Lorentz transform in Appendix I. I think that linearity is implicitly assumed, and I am trying to complete my understanding using the line argument for linearity which I have read in other books and online.

If I understand your question correctly you are envisioning a transformation wherein timelike straight lines are mapped to timelike straight lines, but spacelike straight lines are mapped to curved lines. It is not clear to me that such coordinate transforms exist, but for the sake of argument let’s assume they do.
At this stage of the argument we are not even aware of the distinction between timelike and spacelike lines. So it is hard to see how they could be brought in at all. Instead, a completely different approach may be preferable.
I personally like Pal’s “Nothing but relativity” approach. In it Pal argues from symmetry properties. He interprets the principle of relativity to include the assertion that spacetime is homogenous and isotropic. From these symmetry properties the Lorentz transform is deduced up to an unknown constant $c$ which must be determined by experiment.

In the provided reference, the author sweeps a lot of details under the rug with the "One can similarly argue..." at the top of page 3. In fact, borrowing his notation, I don't see the physical argument for why $T(x,t,v)$ is linear in $x$. Can you explain it? It is entirely counterintuitive to me.

To me this answer is entirely unsatisfying because it fails to answer the question mathematically ("Can linearity be proved from the other properties?"), nor does it to answer it physically ("Which physical principle can be used to complete the proof of linearity?"). I am also not convinced by Pal's proof.

@user1892304 well, hopefully someone else can provide you with a satisfying answer. I disagree with your assessment. Nothing is swept under the rug, the reasoning is clear and directly applicable for the other directions. For $T(x,t,v)$ being linear in $x$ simply go through equations 9 - 12 and replace all $X$ with $T$. The math holds, the motivation with the rod is superfluous. It does answer your question, deriving it from homogeneity and isotropy.
